# Converting time from API into Human readable from

Tags: android, android-api-levels

I am using earthquake API when I fetch time of earthquake it is not in Human readable as shown below.

Time in API is in Long form and I want to display it in listview as 00/00/0000

This is how I fetch time and some more data from API :

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        l=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_id);
        queue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        request();
        l.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
              ApiClass apiClass=list.get(position);
               Uri uri=Uri.parse(apiClass.getUrl());
               Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,uri);
               startActivity(intent);
              }
          });

    }


                   @Override
                   public void onResponse(String response) {

                       try {
                           JSONObject ob1=new JSONObject(response);
                           JSONArray ob2=ob1.getJSONArray("features");
                           for (int i=0;i<ob2.length();i++){
                               JSONObject ob3=ob2.getJSONObject(i);
                               JSONObject ob4=ob3.getJSONObject("properties");

                               String title=ob4.getString("title");
                               Double mag=ob4.getDouble("mag");
                               Long time=ob4.getLong("time");
                               String u=ob4.getString("url");

                               list.add(new ApiClass(title,mag,time,u));

                           }
                           CustomAdapter adapter=new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this,list);
                           l.setAdapter(adapter);
                       }
                       catch (JSONException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }

                       // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                   }
               }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
           @Override
               public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
       });

       queue.add(stringRequest);
     }
}
```

Following is my custom adapter java class:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View v=convertView;
           if(convertView==null){
               v= LayoutInflater.from(c).inflate(R.layout.custom_layout,parent,false);
           }
           ApiClass ob=(ApiClass) arrayList.get(position);
        CircleImageView image=v.findViewById(R.id.image_id);
        TextView tv1=v.findViewById(R.id.title_id);
        TextView tv2=v.findViewById(R.id.magnitude_id);
        TextView tv3=v.findViewById(R.id.time_id);
        tv1.setText(ob.getTitle().toString());
        tv2.setText(ob.getMag().toString());
        tv3.setText(ob.getTime().toString());
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.mouse);

        return v;
    }
```

This is my Apiclass which return value to set value in listview:

```
    public ApiClass(String title, Double mag, Long time, String url) {
        this.title = title;
        this.mag = mag;
        this.time = time;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public Double getMag() {

        return mag;
    }

    public Long getTime() {

        return  time;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

}
```

Comment: Time is like this :1737394537378

Comment: Only showing number

Comment: The above long integer type time is an example  what I am getting ,it is not correct

Comment: the time that I am getting is same  as above in long integer formate

Comment: https://earthquake.usgs.gov/fdsnws/event/1/

Comment: I have added ApiClass

Comment: Edit your Question to show sample of the problematic data. Don't make your readers comb through Comments.

Answer (score 0):

convert long time stamp to Date object

```
Date date = new Date(long)
```

then use java provided SimpleDateFormat API to convert time to your desired format,
for example to get **2018-Mar-1**

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MMM-d")
String date = sdf.format(date) // date object created above
```

Comment: where I should use date object

Comment: to format the time stamp through SimpleDateFormat object

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_737_394_537_378L  )
```

> 2025-01-20T17:35:37.378Z

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes.

You apparently have a count of milliseconds since an epoch of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z.

```
Instant instant =  Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_737_394_537_378L  ) ;
```

Generate a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2025-01-20T17:35:37.378Z

For other formats, use `DateTimeFormatter`. Search Stack Overflow for many many examples and discussions already posted.

To see the same moment in the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region, apply a time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Kolkata" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Answer (score -1):

This has worked for me :

```
   private String getDate(long time){
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
    String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(time));
    String date = ""+dateString;
    return date;
}
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).